# Position issue back button in Root UINavigationController

Tags: swift, layout, uinavigationcontroller, back-button, safearealayoutguide

I'm comming to you with a very weird issue I'm facing and I'm not able to solve.

Assuming I've this pattern in my app (which is pretty common)

```
                     ...
                   ↗︎ UINavigationController (1)
UITabBarController → UINavigationController (2)
                   ↘︎ UINavigationController (3)
                     ...
```

I'm facing an issue on launch with the very first UINavigationController stack (3) : the back button item goes under the iPhone time (in the iPhone X / XS / 11 ) notch.

### Issue (right after launch)

First controller of UINavigationController
[image]
Second controller of UINavigationController
[image]

If I change the initial tab (to (1) or (2) by example), the issue moves to this tab.

**But** the weirdest here, is that if I navigate into my app (i.e. go to another tab), and then come back, the issue have gone and the back button is at it right position

### Expected behavior (after navigating)

[image: Good position]

### Things I've tried

Changing `collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` don't help either.
[image: Changing contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior]